# a verb "know" as a transitive verb and an intransitive verb

Tags: verbs, objects

Can I say only "Do you know?" without saying the object in this case?:

> I'm looking for a flower shop around here. Do you know?

How can I distinguish cases where I need to say object and where I don't need to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is correct.

A dictionary can indicate if a verb requires a direct object. But in many cases you can guess, if meaning seems clear without an object, it probably doesn't need one (there are exceptions)

Comment: To me, it would seem natural to say "Do you know [of] one?" Otherwise, the question could (hypothetically) mean "Do you know that I'm looking for a flower shop?"

Comment: I agree with your general point, but in this specific case, leaving out an object sounds strange and non-fluent.  "Do you know?" by itself sounds like it's only referring to a fact.

Answer (score 7):

"Do you know?" by itself is grammatically correct, but not what a (US) native speaker would say here.  *Do you know?* by itself would only be used if you had previously used a sentence about knowledge, like

> When did King Frederick live?  Do you know?

> I don't know where he keeps his money.  Do you know?

In this last example you could even just use *Do you?*, since *know* is the main verb.

If you use the bare *Do you know?* after a statement, it sounds like you're asking the other person if they know that statement, which is a strange thing to ask because you just told them.

Comment: It's not what any English speaker would say. I'm from the UK!

Comment: While that seems to be the literal meaning of the question, since it's such a strange thing no one would interpret it that way. So the implied object is "where a flower shop is". It might not be a common way to ask, but it's also easily understood.